# Is there a way to make text fly in ONCLICK in Captivate 4?

Tags: adobe, adobe-captivate

Is there a way to make bullets appear as the user clicks the screen.  (Kind of like a click for more)

Thanks in advance, I can not find this functionality anywhere.

EDIT: If it can't be done, than "NO" would be an acceptable answer...

I would simply just like the text caption to go from invisible, to visible on click. Then when they click again, it shows the next text caption underneath it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean where the user clicks that it would make a bullet or to an already defined list and you just want to add another bullet?

Comment: I would simply just like the text caption to go from invisible, to visible on click.  Then when they click again, it shows the next text caption underneath it.